# Difference between meta-regression and linear regression in Stata?

Tags: regression, stata

I have a question about meta regression. I'm performing a metareg with the variable: 'sumvariable' which can have a value of (0-6). I want to see what this variable does to the mortality rate, expressed as RD or OR. 
These are the codes I generated:

```
gen or = (death1/nondeath1)/(death2/nondeath2)
gen logor = log(or)
gen selogor = sqrt((1/death1)+(1/nondeath1)+(1/death2)+(1/nondeath2))
gen rd = (death1/Npat1) - (death2/Npat2)
gen risk1= death1/Npat1
gen risk2= death2/Npat2
gen serd= sqrt(risk1*(1-risk1)/Npat1) + (risk2*(1-risk2)/Npat2)
```

When I perform a metareg for RD: “metareg rd sumvariable, wsse(serd)” I get an error:  *zero or negative wsse() not allowed*. So I performed a new metareg analysis without the following codes:

```
gen risk1= death1/Npat1
gen risk2= death2/Npat2
gen serd= sqrt(risk1*(1-risk1)/Npat1) + (risk2*(1-risk2)/Npat2)
```

And then the metareg does give an output, however now it has the same standard error as when I perform a metareg with OR as outcome (see output). When I perform a linear regression with the same variables, the standard error differs between RD and OR (what you would expect). Why does metareg give the same SE for OR and RD?

Stata output I got with similar SE: 
*the number of observations between RD and OR differs due to zero cells in some studies*
[image: Screenshot of STATA output]
When I perform a metareg with with CVA instead of mortality (generated with the following codes), the metareg does give 2 different SE's for RD and OR:

```
gen or = (cerebro1/noncerebro1)/(cerebro2/noncerebro2)
gen logor = log(or)
gen selogor = sqrt((1/cerebro1)+(1/noncerebro1)+(1/cerebro2)+(1/noncerebro2))
gen rd = (cerebro1/Npat1) - (cerebro2/Npat2)
```

STATA output for CVA: 
[image: STATA output for CVA]

Comment: How are you calculating the SE of RR and OR?

Comment: The effect sizes for metareg should (I believe) be log(OR) and log(RR).

Comment: The SE for OR is calculated as follows:

gen logor = log(or)
gen selogor = sqrt((1/deathgroup1)+(1/nondeathgroup1)+(1/deathgroup2)+(1/nondeathgroup2))

When I use 'metareg logor sumvariable, wsse (selogor)', I still get the same SE for both logor and RD. 

I am performing a metareg with Risk differences RD and not RR.

Comment: Welcome Tessa, this seems to be a Stata-specific (and, actually, a *metareg*-specific) question, so I have voted to shift it to StackOverflow (where Stata-specific questions are usually handled). I have often found it useful to write directly to package authors with queries about their add-on packages (as a package author, I myself entertain such questions frequently). Roger M. Harbord, the author of the current version of metareg, includes his contact information at the end of the help-file for metareg, which also suggests that you might find contacting him directly fruitful.

Comment: @Alexis - I don't think it is. Tessa is using metareg and Stata, but it's not an issue related to that, it's an issue related to meta-regression.

Comment: @Tessa - can you enter all the code? Your metareg code says that you are using OR, but your code in the comment says you are using logor. It's hard to help if we don't know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Jeremy, this is the code I used for the output I showed in my question: 

gen or = (death1/nondeath1)/(death2/nondeath2)
gen selogor = sqrt((1/death1)+(1/nondeath1)+(1/death2)+(1/nondeath2))
gen rd = (death1/Npat1) - (death2/Npat2)

**metareg rd sumvariable, wsse (se)**
**metareg or sumvariable, wsse (selogor)**

**regres rd sumvariable**
**regres or sumvariable**


The logor code I used in my comment was to show what codes I used when performing a metareg with log(OR) (What you suggested I should try in your 2nd comment). Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: @Tessa - that's different to the code you posted in the question, and the SE of the RD is not calculated anywhere (that I can see). It might be clearer if you edit the question.

Comment: Here's 1 guess. If you don't write a full variable name, and Stata can uniquely identify a variable based on the partial name, it will use it. You never define the variable se in your code, but there is a variable selogor. If you just type se, Stata will use selogor - that's not the right se.

Comment: @Jeremy, Thank you for your help. I'm going to look into your suggestion. However I find it strange that when I perform metareg with CVA instead of mortality, the metareg does give 2 different SE's for RD and OR, when I use a similar syntax for CVA: gen or = (cerebro1/noncerebro1)/(cerebro2/noncerebro2)
gen logor = log(or)
gen selogor = sqrt((1/cerebro1)+(1/noncerebro1)+(1/cerebro2)+(1/noncerebro2))
gen rd = (cerebro1/Npat1) - (cerebro2/Npat2)

Comment: See update in question for stata output

Comment: I find it strange too, but you have not posted your code that generates the se for both RR and OR. I can't help without that code.

Comment: The SE for OR should be log transformed so I generated the following code: 
gen or = (death1/nondeath1)/(death2/nondeath2) 
gen logor = log(or)
gen selogor = sqrt((1/death1)+(1/nondeath1)+(1/death2)+(1/nondeath2))
I did not generate a SE code for RD, because when generate the following code:  
gen rd = (death1/Npat1) - (death2/Npat2)
gen risk1= death1/Npat1
gen risk2= death2/Npat2
gen serd= sqrt(risk1*(1-risk1)/Npat1) + (risk2*(1-risk2)/Npat2) -->
metareg rd sumvariable, wsse(serd) ---> then I get an error message “zero or negative wsse() not allowed”  (due to zero events in some cells).

Comment: I don't know what codes I can give you other than these, so I hope it helps! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If it gives an error for the second with d, how do you have a result for the rd meta-analysis. I think it is using the wrong side.  (Also of you could edit the question so that all of the code is in it, it works be easier to read.)

Comment: I edited my question a little, hopefully it makes it a bit more clear. Could you explain to me what you mean with that it might be 'using the wrong side'? Any thoughts on how to deal with that?

Comment: The point made by @Alexis earlier seems quite correct. This is focusing on right and wrong code and seems off-topic to me.

Comment: I did email the package author (Roger Harbord) as Alexis suggested, but I have not heard from him yet. So all thoughts on my question are helpful :)